# Parse command output before it is done

Tags: python, fabric

I'm handling deploys with fabric and one step is to upgrade a debian package. I'm executing

```
sudo('aptitude install packagename')
```

and it will ask me:

```
[server] out: 1 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 110 not upgraded.
[server] out: Need to get 40.7 kB of archives. After unpacking 1,024 B will be used.
[server] out: Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?]
```

I want to make sure that there is exactly 1 packages upgraded and 0 to remove. I'm trying to parse the question to answer based on that rule, but I can't figure out how to access the text before the command has finished executing. Is there a way?

Comment: `how to access the text before the command has finished executing.` Would you elaborate? Do you mean you want to parse the string before sending `Y`?

Comment: @That1Guy yes, exactly, I'm having trouble articulating myself today. I want to parse the question and answer `Y/N` depending on the text without having to answer manually, since it's for multiple servers, but not just assume `Y` since it might want to uninstall or do other bad things.

Comment: Arent you able to use an api (http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/index.html) instead of parsing text? I'm not sure what happens if `apt` is localized.

Comment: @Caramiriel I'll have a look and see if I can use it with `execute()`

Comment: I almost gave up, this turned out to be a bit of a mess; `yes 'yes' | sudo aptitude install <pakage>` works for me. At one point i got desperate and i was already by here: `sudo aptitude install pidgin -o Aptitude::CmdLine::Assume-Yes=true -y` ... i digress, the first one works.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi This would work to assume yes, but it will also assume yes for other actions than upgrade. I've had issues in the past when dependencies made aptitude to think that the best solution was to uninstall the package and I want to be sure that can not happen, therefore I want to make sure it only answers yes if 1 upgrade and 0 remove is in the string...

Comment: @Caramiriel I wrote the code using the apt library and then realised that I can not execute it remotely using fabric, unfortunately.

Comment: how about something like this?? `if [ $(yes n | sudo aptitude install <pakage> | grep -c "1 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove") -eq 1 ]; then echo "remove the echo: yes | sudo aptitude install <pakage>"; fi` (you may have to just run it like: `yes n | sudo aptitude install <pakage>` and look at the string it gives you and THEN plug it into the grep) -- ps, why are you using aptitude? -- just wondering.